# SQL Assign 1 to All rows for each member for condition based on one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have this monthly snapshot table:

| ID | Date | Percent_Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Member1 | 2021-12-31 | NULL |
| Member1 | 2023-01-31 | .8 |
| Member1 | 2023-02-28 | -.3 |
| Member2 | 2021-12-31 | NULL |
| Member2 | 2023-01-31 | -.5 |
| Member2 | 2023-02-28 | .8 |

which contains the Member's ID, the Date (End of Month Snapshot Date), and the percent change in balances from the previous month (ie: if the previous month was 5 and the current month is 2, the percent change is (2-5)/(5) = -.6)

I'm trying to get a Target variable that marks 1 if the percent change of the current month vs the first ever month is <= -30% and then also populates all other rows after that, regardless if the percent change of the current month vs the first month is > -30%

| ID | Date | Percent_Change | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Member1 | 2021-12-31 | NULL | NULL |
| Member1 | 2023-01-31 | .8 | 0 |
| Member1 | 2023-02-28 | -.3 | 1 |
| Member1 | 2023-03-31 | .65 | 1 |
| Member2 | 2021-12-31 | NULL | NULL |
| Member2 | 2023-01-31 | -.5 | 1 |
| Member2 | 2023-02-28 | .8 | 1 |
| Member2 | 2023-03-31 | .3 | 1 |

Here's what I have so far:

```
with Dec2021Balance as(
select 
SnapshotDate
,MemberID
,Balance
from
balance_snapshot_table
where SnapshotDate= '2021-12-31'
)

select 
tbl2.SnapshotDate
,tbl2.MemberID
,(tbl2.Balance-Dec2021Balance.Balance)/(Dec2021Balance.Balance)
from
balance_snapshot_table tbl2
right join Dec2021Balance on Dec2021Balance.MemberID= tbl2.MemberID
```

This table gets the percent change from the current month and December 2021. I was thinking of just adding a case when statement that populates the target variable with 1 if the difference <=-30%, but this doesn't handle cases where the differences is >-30%.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just edited the query to include what I have so far. I'm having trouble with cases where the percent difference between the current month and december 2021 are >-30%

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.

`first_value` gives us the first balance per member id:

```
select b.*,
    first_value(balance) over(partition by memberID order by snapshotDate) first_balance
from balance_snapshot_table b
```

Now we can compute the change ratio on each further balance (the subquery is just a syntactic sugar to avoid typing the window functions more than once).

```
select b.*, 
    ( balance - first_balance ) / nullif(first_balance, 0) ratio_change
from (
    select b.*,
        first_value(balance) over(partition by memberID order by snapshotDate) first_balance
    from balance_snapshot_table b
) b
```

As for the flag, we can check if the ratio of each member ever dropped behind our target using window functions again:

```
select b.*, 
    case when min(ratio_change) over(partition by memberID order by snapshotDate) <= -.03 then 1 else 0 end flag
from (
    select b.*, 
        ( balance - first_balance ) / nullif(first_balance, 0) ratio_change
    from (
        select b.*,
            first_value(balance) over(partition by memberID order by snapshotDate) first_balance
        from balance_snapshot_table b
    ) b
) b
```

Again, the multiple suqueries are here to make the syntax easier to write and read - on the other hand the query scans the table only once, so this should be more efficient than approaches that use joins.